# [JS move element in middle of screen

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner in JS and I need to help someone to do one task but I'm stuck.
She need to move element from bottom outside of the screen to the middle of the screen at the display of the page.

She try this but nothing happened:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myimg = $( this ).find(" div ");

//Just trying to move div but nothing
  myimg.animate({transform: 'translateY(150px)'}, 800, 'ease')
})
```

```css
#first {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#middle {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#last {
  background-color:#F16668;
  margin-top:150px;
  margin-left:100px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  lama
</div>

<div id="middle">
  lama
</div>

<div id="last">
  lama
</div>
```

Can you help me please ?
Thank you a lot !

Comment: Code Snippet not working and what you want to move , background color from div last to middle?
You must be missing jquery , jquery-ui.min.js (for ease function)

Comment: I need to move the text (in task it's an img) from bottom to the middle  of the screen. And thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you understand how to animate with CSS classes and transitions.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $("#middle").addClass('goUp');
}, 1000); // move up after 1 second


$("#middle").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('goUp');
}); // move on click
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#middle {
  display: block;
  top: 100px;
}
#middle.goUp {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="middle">Click to move</div>
```